# keras r how to save a model and continue training

Tags: r, keras

I'm following the example here: https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/lstm_text_generation.html

I'm struggling to figure out how to save the model and then at a later date continue training (possibly on a different computer).

thanks!

Comment: If it works like in python, the model object should have a `save` and a `save_weights` method. Import the `load_model` function from `keras.models`, or call a `model$load_weights` on saved weights.

Comment: How would you continue training the model after you load it?

Comment: `model$fit` or `model$fit_generator`

Answer (score 0):

in keras save your model architecture and weights.
then again every time to load and fit model with your new input datasets.

like this way.

```
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN, TimeDistributed

model=Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(input_shape=(None, 2),
                    return_sequences=True, 
                    units=5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(activation='sigmoid', units=3)))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'rmsprop')
model.fit(inputs, outputs, epochs = 500, batch_size = 32)

model.save('my_model.h5')

from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('my_model.h5')

# continue fitting
model.fit(inputs, outputs, epochs = 500, batch_size = 32)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56802013/8442616 i also faced this issue. once check it this link.