# is it possible to do continuous training in keras for multi-class classification problem?

Tags: keras

I was tried to continues training in keras.
because I was build keras multiclass classification model after I have new labels and values. so I want to build a new model without retraining. that is why I tried continuous train in keras.

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(training_data, labels, epochs=20, batch_size=1)

model.save("keras_model.h5")
```

after completing save the model , i want to do continues training. so i tried,

```
model1 = load_model("keras_model.h5")
model1.fit(new_input, new_label, epochs=20, batch_size=1)
model1.save("keras_model.h5")
```

I tried this. but it was thrown an error. like previously 10 classes. but now we add new class means an error occurred.

so what is my question is, is it possible for continues training in keras for multiclass classification for a new class?

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Received
>   a label value of 10 which is outside the valid range of [0, 9).  Label
>   values: 10     [[{{node
>   loss/dense_7_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach for this type of situations is to define a common model that contains most of the inner layers and is reusable; and then a second model that defines the output layer and thus the number of classes. The inner model can be reused in subsequent outer models.

Untested example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

def make_inner_model():
  """ An example model that takes 42 features and outputs a
  transformation vector.
  """
  inp = Input(shape=(42,), name='in')
  h1 = Dense(80, activation='relu')(inp)
  h2 = Dense(40)(h1)
  h3 = Dense(60, activation='relu')(h2)
  out = Dense(32)(h3)
  return Model(inp, out)

def make_outer_model(inner_model, n_classes):
  inp = Input(shape=(42,), name='inp')
  hidden = inner_model(inp)
  out = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(hidden)
  model = Model(inp, out)
  model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')
  return model

inner_model = make_inner_model()

inner_model.save('inner_model_untrained.h5')

model1 = make_outer_model(inner_model, 10)
model1.summary()

# model1.fit()
# inner_model.save_weights('inner_model_weights_1.h5')

model2 = make_outer_model(inner_model, 12)

# model2.fit()
# inner_model.save_weights('inner_model_weights_2.h5')
```

Comment: @MuruganR edited the answer with a code snippet that reuses a set of hidden layers across multiple models with different output layers.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. really you are great. it is working fine.

Comment: sir in this scenario, how we have to save model? if we save model weights means again how will load without make_inner_model(),  make_outer_model() function?

Comment: You can call ```inner_model.save('filename')``` and then use ```keras.models.load_model()```. Or you can choose to use ```model.save_weights```.